# Search field wouldn't move to the left except by using margin-right (which is not advisable)

Tags: css, margin-left

I don't understand why the search field on our [website](http://www.furstenberglaw.com.au/) follows a `margin-right` CSS command BUT NOT a `margin-left` CSS command. How come?

```
.header-top .search-field {
    border-top: none;
    border-bottom: none;
    height: 34px;
    border-color: #EDEDED;
    outline: none;
}
```

The search field shows up only after clicking on the search icon to the top left of the page. This icon also previously wouldn't move to the left through a `margin-left` CSS command but I was finally able to move it through the `right` CSS command. I wonder what's the difference between the two.

Will appreciate feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Try to do below css :

```
.header-top .search-form{
position : initial
}
```

Comment: Nope. Didn't work. The field was actually originally to the right and the phone number to the left. I switched their positions but the field just wouldn't follow.

Comment: try to put '!important' after initial like this 'position:initial !important;'

Comment: Thanks. I finally got it figured by paying attention to the commands for `header-top .search-form`. Turns out the issue was in there. Interesting how Firebug never showed the section and was instead pointing me to something else.

Comment: @SandyAlbaytarJr. Your welcome. If it worth to you don't forget to accept my answer by clicking right check mark on my answer.

Comment: It wasn't the exact answer so I can't check it otherwise would be misleading. But it helped me to pay attention to the appropriate section :)